# How to use the content of one dataframe to index another multi-level index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have the following dataframes `site_1_df` and `site_2_df (both are similar):

`site_1_df`:

[image]

And the following dataframe:

```
site_1_index_df = pd.DataFrame(site_1_df.index.values.tolist(), columns=["SiteNumber", "WeekNumber", "PG"])
site_2_index_df = pd.DataFrame(site_2_df.index.values.tolist(), columns=["SiteNumber", "WeekNumber", "PG"])
index_intersection = pd.merge(left=site_1_index_df, right=site_2_index_df, 
                              on=["WeekNumber", "PG"], how="inner")[["WeekNumber", "PG"]]
```

`index_intersection`:

[image]

Consequently, it is clear that `site_1_df` and `site_2_df` are multi-level indexed dataframes. Therefore, I woulld like to use the `index_intersection` to index the above dataframe. Or, If I am indexing from site_1_df, then I want a subset of the rows from the same dataframe. And technically, I should get back a dataframe that has (8556 rows x 6 columns), i.e., the same number of rows of index_intersection. How can I achieve that efficiently in pandas?

I tried:

```
index_intersection = pd.merge(left=site_1_index_df, right=site_2_index_df, 
                              on=["WeekNumber", "PG"], how="inner")[["SiteNumber_x", "WeekNumber", "PG"]]

index_intersection = index_intersection.rename(columns={"SiteNumber_x": "SiteNumber"})

index_intersection = index_intersection.set_index(["SiteNumber", "WeekNumber", "PG"])
index_intersection
```

And I got:

[image]

However, indexing the dataframe using another dataframe such as:

```
site_2_df.loc[index_intersection]
# or
site_2_df.loc[index_intersection.index]
# or
site_2_df.loc[index_intersection.index.values]
```

will give me an error:

```
NotImplementedError: Indexing a MultiIndex with a DataFrame key is not implemented
```

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Please provide a desired output.

Comment: If I am indexing from `site_1_df`, then I want a subset of the rows. And technically, I should get back a dataframe that has (8556 rows x 6 columns), i.e., the same number of rows of `index_intersection`. I hope this make things clearer.

Comment: Write out, in your question, exactly what you're looking for.  You'll get a lot better answers.  Obviously truncate the # of rows, but include all columns, indicies, and at least 3 or 4 rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that I can find the intersection of 2 dataframes, based on their index through:

```
sites_common_rows = pd.merge(left=site_1_df.reset_index([0]), right=site_2_df.reset_index([0]), 
                                 left_index=True, right_index=True, how="inner")
```

The `reset_index([0])` above is used to ignore the SiteNumber since this totally different from one dataframe to another. Consequently, I am able to find the inner join between two dataframes from their indexes.